# How do I create a Rust function or macro for debugging that gets optimized away in a release build?

Tags: debugging, rust

In a debug build, I want to check for OpenGL errors after almost every OpenGL call to ease debugging. As this is a costly operation, I don't want to do it in a release build. Right now I'm using functions like:

```
pub fn debug_panic_on_errors() {
    if cfg!(debug_assertions) {
        get_errors().unwrap();
    }
}
```

Am I correct in assuming that this method will always be optimized away completely? Is there a better, more future-proof way?

Comment: Or you could use an [existing OpenGL crate](https://crates.io/crates/glium) that already uses runtime and compile time checks.

Comment: I literally just submitted an issue two hours ago proposing a `debug` macro: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41223. It'd be good to show that there are other people who'd use that feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In release mode the function will be expanded to `if false { … }` which is very trivial to optimize away, so yes you could just use it as-is.

---

If you are being paranoid you could `#[cfg]` two functions like

```
#[cfg(debug_assertions)]
pub fn debug_panic_on_errors() { 
    get_errors().unwrap();
}

#[cfg(not(debug_assertions))]
pub fn debug_panic_on_errors() {
}
```

so that the outcome is chosen during parsing, to ensure we don't rely on the optimizer. But I don't really recommend this...