# Will the Rust compiler exclude branches dependent on constants from the compiled executable?

Tags: rust

I have the code:

```rust
const DEBUG_MODE: bool = false;

fn main() {
    if DEBUG_MODE {
        println!("In debug mode!");
    }
    println!("Normal code");
}
```

Will the Rust compiler remove the branching so it is the same as:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("Normal code");
}
```

Will there be any differences in the compiled assembly output?

In the case where `DEBUG_MODE` is `true`, will it inline the branch or will it actually do the check in assembly?

If we have a function like this:

```
fn debug_fn() {
    if !DEBUG_MODE {
        return;
    }
    println!("Some debug function");
}
```

If `DEBUG_MODE` is `false`, will all the calls to it be optimized out or will it still have some form of overhead?

Comment: yes: https://blog.rust-lang.org/inside-rust/2019/12/02/const-prop-on-by-default.html

Comment: In any case, I'd recommend using the #[cfg] attribute: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/attribute/cfg.html

Comment: Even without MIR-level const propagation, this is the kind of thing LLVM would happily would have done. MIR-level const propagation was mostly about compile-time performance, not runtime performance.

Comment: Note that using a `DEBUG` constant like that isn't the idiomatic way. `#[cfg]` is. Using a constant forces that the code must compile in both debug and release mode even if it's going to be unused in release mode.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/TbY8Gr9fz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will. As [a simpler example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=488c21ce1c774f37cfcdec4e6953e485):

```rust
const DEBUG_MODE: bool = false;

pub fn example() {
    if DEBUG_MODE {
        call_me();
    }
    call_me();
}

#[inline(never)]
fn call_me() {
    println!("called");
}
```

When compiled in release mode, Rust 1.54 produces this x86_64 assembly for `example` when `DEBUG_MODE` is `false`:

```
playground::example:
    jmp playground::call_me
```

When `DEBUG_MODE` is `true`:

```
playground::example:
    pushq   %rax
    callq   playground::call_me
    popq    %rax
    jmp playground::call_me
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, it's more idiomatic to use `cfg` attributes for [conditional compilation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html) as it can be handled at a earlier level in the compiler. This means you can have some types of invalid code present. For example:

```rust
pub fn example() {
    #[cfg(some_debug_mode)]
    {
        oops_i_never_defined_this_function();
        call_me();
    }
    call_me();
}
```

Less commonly used, but still valuable, is the [`cfg!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.cfg.html) macro. This resolves to a `true` or a `false` and you rely on the same dead code elimination as the original case:

```rust
pub fn example() {
    if cfg!(some_debug_mode) {
        call_me();
    }
    call_me();
}
```

See also:

- [How to check release / debug builds using cfg in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39204908/155423)
- [Does a compiled Rust executable exclude unused code from dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52057069/155423)
- [Will Rust optimize away unused function arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63697356/155423)
- [How do I create a Rust function or macro for debugging that gets optimized away in a release build?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43352134/155423)

Comment: Any other see also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63858774/different-versions-of-the-same-function-with-conditional-compilation-in-rust